# this code was supposed to invert a string given by the first argument, but it has a compilation error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
    public class ex4 {

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
   int strlength=length(args);
   InvertString(args, strlength, 0);
}

public static int length(String args[]) {
    int i=0;
    int count=0;
    while(Character.isLetter(args[0].charAt(i))){
        count++;
        i++;}
    return count;
        }




public static void InvertString(String args[], int i, int x){

    char a= args[0].charAt(x);
        args[0].charAt(x)=args[0].charAt(i-1-x);
        args[0].charAt(i-1-x)=a;
    x++;

    if(x<(i/2)) InvertString(args,i,x);
    }
}
```

The compilation error is ex4.java:27: error: unexpected type required: variable found: value ex4.java:28: error: unexpected type required: variable found: value

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Yeah, you can't do anything even close to that.  You can't say `foo.charAt(i) = anything`.  You can't modify a `String` at all, actually, you can only create an entirely new one.

Comment: guess i'll create another one then, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code defies a number of java conventions. To get an inversion of a string you simply could use

```
 String reversedString = new StringBuilder(args[0]).reverse().toString();
```

The length of the string is returned by method length():

```
int length = args[0].length();
```

However, I take this code for an algorithmic exercise, so will comment it accordingly.

First of all args is an array of strings, so you should exchange argument of String[] to String in your InverseString method, as I see you want args[0] String to be inverted.

Second, it is a bad practice to reassign argument values in a body of a message and it is preferable to declare a new variable. Arguments are passed by value in java so if you change the argument value, the calling method would not see the change. However, if the argument is the reference to a mutable object, you can change that object.

Third, String is  immutable in java - once an instance was created, you cannot change the contents, only assign the reference to a new String. So either your InvertString should change from return type void to return type String and main method should assign a variable to the new value OR you should declare a mutable object to store your intermediate values. For character manipulation you have mutable StringBuffer and StringBuilder classes. StringBuilder is more appropriate because you don't have multithreading in your code.

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
   StringBuilder arg = new StringBuilder(args[0]);
   int strlength = arg.length();
   InvertString(arg, strlength, 0);
}

 public static void InvertString(StringBuilder arg, int i, int x) {
     char a = arg.charAt(x); //char a= args[0].charAt(x);
     arg.setCharAt(x,arg.charAt(i-1-x)); //args[0].charAt(x)=args[0].charAt(i-1-x);
     arg.setCharAt(i-1-x,a); // args[0].charAt(i-1-x)=a;

     if( x < (i/2)) 
         InvertString(arg,i,x + 1); // replace x++ with x + 1 to avoid argument manipulation
 }
```

This algorithm will compile, however it still has an error - the middle characters are going to be replaced twice (back to original) in the case of even length string. I'll let you figure the fix. Good luck!